# Pyinstaller with anaconda in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

So i wrote a little programm in python with use of tkinter. The repo is found here: https://github.com/Odatas/MeisterTools

I now want to create an exe so people only need to use the exe when they want to use the program. But the exe i create with pyinstaller doesnt work and throws the error:

Import Error: cannot import name 'travel' from '**main**'

The cmd i opend to creat the exe is directly out of anaconda envoirment.

I cd into the folder where all the scripts are and then run it like this:

pyinstaller --onefile patrickstools2.py

I even tried to make every import an hidden import:

pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=**init** --hidden-import=**main** --hidden-import=checker --hidden-import=contact --hidden-import=dangers --hidden-import=droptable --hidden-import=importexcel --hidden-import=odatasfunctions --hidden-import=randomenpc --hidden-import=scrolltest --hidden-import=sonstiges --hidden-import=travel patrickstools2.py

that doesnt help either. I added the path through Anaconda to the PYTHONPATH variable...so it should be know in any way shape or form.

The complet code is in Anaconda. The Error gets thrown in the import section of the main file:

```py
# page classes import   
import os

try:
     import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
     import tkinter as tk

try:
     import ttk
     py3 = False
except ImportError:
     import tkinter.ttk as ttk
     py3 = True

# page classes import   
from . import travel 
from . import contact
from . import dangers 
from . import sonstiges
from . import randomenpc
```

I allready created an exe with pyinstaller from a previous version. But i made some changes to the structure of the programm. The run.py is only there because i work with spyder and as far as i know spyder needs it because else the import doesnt work correctly.

Comment: You should put modules `travel`, `contact`, etc. next to your script. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, every python file regarding that project is in the same folder.

Comment: So remove relative import and just use `import travel`, etc. in your script.